# I am confuse how to replace string preg replace

Tags: php

I am stuck the whole day thinking how to change `[img]imagesrc[/img]` to `<img src='imagesrc' />`.
Well, in this case i can use `str_replace` to solve. Just curious is it possible to do it with `preg_replace`?

another problem i cant solve using `str_replace` is change `[size=14]text[/size]` to something like `<font style='font-size:14px'>text</font>`.

Someone please help me.

**Edited**

```
$content = [img]imagesrc[/img];
$content = str_replace("[img]", "<img src='", $content);
$content = str_replace("[/img]", "' style='width:100%'/>", $content);
```

This is what I had done with [img] using `str_replace`. Just want to know any solution by using `preg_replace` since I cant solved `[size=14]text[/size]` with `str_replace`.

I just wonder why people always complaint my question is not related or any other reason. I am a newbie thats why I seeking for help here. Isn't here a platform seeking for help? I am not asking for answer directly without trying, I just asking for alternative and better solution to improve my skill.

Comment: Since you've been working all day at it...you should post the code you've tried.

Comment: Show some code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
<?php
$content = '[img]imagesrc[/img][size=10]Text with size of 10[/size]';
$html = preg_replace("#\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]#iUs", '<img src="$1"/>', $content);
$html = preg_replace('#\[size\=(\d+)\](.+)\[\/size\]#iUs', '<font style="font-size: $1px;">$2</font>', $html);
print $html;
?>
```

You could also make it a function, like:

```
function parseBBcode($content) {
    $html = $content;

    $html = preg_replace('#\[img\](.+)\[\/img\]#iUs', '<img src="$1" alt="Image" />', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('#\[size\=(\d+)\](.+)\[\/size\]#iUs', '<font style="font-size: $1px;">$2</font>', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('#\[b\](.+)\[\/b\]#iUs', '<b>$1</b>', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('#\[link(?|=[\'"]?+([^]"\']++)[\'"]?+\]([^[]++)|](([^[]++)))\[/link\]#iUs', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $html);

    return $html;
}
```

And then use it like:

```
print parseBBcode('[img]imagesrc[/img] [img]imagesrc2[/img] [img]imagesrc3[/img] [size=10]Text with size of 10[/size] [b]text to be bolded[/b] [link=http://www.google.com]Link to google[/link] [link]http://www.google.com[/link');
```

or:

```
$content = '[img]imagesrc[/img] [img]imagesrc2[/img] [img]imagesrc3[/img] [size=10]Text with size of 10[/size] [b]text to be bolded[/b] [link=http://www.google.com]Link to google[/link] [link]http://www.google.com[/link]';
print parseBBcode($content);
```

Comment: So you decided to unaccept my answer so that i get -15 reputation, thanks :)

Comment: sorry... i think i misclick last time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iI6mL9/1):

```
preg_replace("/\\[img\\](.*)\\[\\/img\\]/", '<img src="$1"/>', "[img]imagesrc[/img]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem can be solved as thus:

```
preg_replace('/\[img\]([^\[\]]+)\[\/img\]/',"<img src='$1'/>",$string);
```

And your second:

```
preg_replace('/\[size=(\d+)\](.+)\[\/size\]/',"<font style='font-size:$1px'>$2</font>",$s);
```

Regex is invaluable, and these are quite simple. I'd highly recommend [learning more about regex](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=learn%20regex) so you can write your own regexes for your application.

Comment: yeah.. I think I have to put more afford on this. Thanks for your suggestion.